# How to Find Element By it's Attribute Name and Attribute Value in PI-Web API

Tags: osisoft

Is there a way to find the Element by it's Attribute Name and Attribute Value in PI-Web API.

Input:

AttributeName = SAP_ID

AttributeValue = <>

Expected Output:

Element that contains attribute that matches this attributename='SAP_ID' and attributevalue=<>

I am looking for your help on how to get this done using PI-WEB API.

Note:

1. I tried with PI-Web API Crawler search ( But this was not encouraged by my technical lead as it requires additional infra/service to be enabled).
2. I tried to convince my technical lead to use ExtendedProperties, but PI-WEB API exposes the element extended properties but does not have any option to search based on it.

Version Information:

ProductTitle: "PI Web API 2018"

ProductVersion: "1.11.0.640"

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to do this is by constructing a list of all the WebID's. Then conduct a For loop that would ping every WEBID to match the Description of that WebID. Then from there you would use the WEBID's that match to identify the Path. You would then parse the Path address down to the Element level you desire...like in this JSON for example:

```
{
  "WebId": "I1EmDqD5loBNH0erqeqJodtALAYIKyyz2F5BGAxQAVXYRDBA",
  "Id": "cbb28260-853d-11e4-80c5-00155d844304",
  "Name": "MachineName",
  **"Description": "Manufacturing Equipment MachineName"**,
  "Path": **"\\\\MyAssetServer\\MyDatabase\\CityName\\EngineeringProcess\\Equipment\\MachineName"**,
  "Paths": null,
  "TemplateName": "MachineName",
  "HasChildren": false,
  "CategoryNames": [
    "Equipment Assets"
  ],
  "ExtendedProperties": {},
  "Errors": null,
  "Links": {
    "Self": "https://wdappprd147/piwebapi/elements/I1EmDqD5loBNH0erqeqJodtALAYIKyyz2F5BGAxQAVXYRDBA"
  }
```

Best of Luck!